# Express - socket.io - session. Refer to user id as socket id

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I am using [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session). I think I was able to setup the basic config by seeing the tutorials:

```
//BASIC CONFIG?

var clients = [];

var session = require("express-session")({
    secret: 'some key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
var sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");
app.use(session);

io.use(function(socket, next){
   next();
});

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
  autoSave:true
})); 

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log("CLIENT CONNECTED");
    var session = socket.handshake.session;
    clients.push(socket);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
       console.log("CLIENT DISCONNECTED");
    });

});
```

What I want to be able to do now is to refer to a specific client socket not by the socket but by the session id that should be assigned to that socket. When a user logins this happens:

```
req.session.user_id = user_id; 
//(user_id is equal to DB {0,1,2,3...} ids
```

I was able to send sockets to specific clients when I did this:

```
clients[0].emit("to_do",info); // I don't know who is client index 0 compared to the login reference...
```

I would like to be able to do this or similar:

```
user_id = 3; // which would have a socket assigned

clients(user_id).emit("to_do",info);
```

That would mean each client would have a socket assigned to its previously assigned id. How could I do this so I could specify the socket by that id? I am not experienced at all with all of this so sorry for any big mistakes. Thanks

Comment: You can get the session id like this `var session_id = socket.handshake.session.id` (you need to place this inside your `io.on('connection....)` method.

Comment: @DavidR but would I be able to specify the user as I wanted to? So that I can specify the socket the way I wanted, will I have to add the user_id to the socket method when he logins and then each time I want to send info to a specific user check which object has the right user_id and use the socket id associated to it to emit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by each socket joining a group named after it's id:

```
socket.join(socket.id);

io.sockets.in(socket.id).emit('to_do', info);

//or

io.sockets.in(clients[0].id).emit('to_do', info);
```

Comment: You might prefer to use `socket.to(socket.id).emit('to_do', info);` instead of `io.sockets.in(socket.id).emit('to_do', info);`, since that will automatically exclude the current socket from the receivers of the emitted event.

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved this out by iterating through the clients list and seeing which one had the socket I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, when using express-socket.io-session the user ID in socket.handshake.session.passport changes when a new user login, I used the below to solve it.

```
    var userID;
    if (!userID){
        userID = socket.handshake.session.userID = socket.handshake.session.passport['user'];
        }
```